# repeatedly merge a single file from another branch

Tags: git

I will begin by acknowledging what I'm trying to do is probably a bad idea. That said, let's say that I'm working on branch "B", and I want to merge file "foo" from master. I issue this command:

```
git checkout master foo
```

So, I've got foo in "B" and everything is working fine. A colleague makes changes to foo on master, and I want to pick those changes up. I repeat the 'git checkout', which finishes without any complaint, or any kind of message at all. I check to see if foo matches the version in master, and I find that it doesn't. It hasn't changed since the initial checkout.

I delete foo, and repeat the 'git checkout' command. foo is now back in the directory, but it's the original foo.

Is there a right way for me to do this wrong thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts here:

1. That's not *merging* a file, that's *overwriting* a file.
2. The syntax you want is `git checkout tree-ish -- path`, or, in Git since 2.23, `git restore --source tree-ish --staged --worktree -- path`.

(Be careful not to use `git checkout -- path`, which is very different.)

The *`tree-ish`* part can be a branch-name like `master`, but remember that when you use a `master`, you are referring to *your* branch-name `master`, not anyone else's branch-name *`master`*.  To refer to someone *else's* `master`, e.g., the `master` that your Git is remembering (and picking up from) the other Git that your Git remembers under the name `origin`, you would want to use `origin/master`, not `master`.  You can also use a raw commit hash.  For instance, after running `git log`, if you spot a particular commit `a123456...` or whatever, and want to copy that file from *that* commit, you can just use the commit's hash ID.<sup>1</sup>

The `--` is usually optional, but I recommend getting into the habit of always using it.<sup>2</sup>  It *guarantees* that no matter what the *file* name is, Git won't accidentally treat it as a branch name, or an option, or whatever.  (For instance, suppose the file is named `master`, or `-f`, or something similar.  These look like branch names and options.  The `--` tells Git: *This is not a branch name, nor an option, nor anything of that sort: it's a file name.*)

The *path* part is simply the path of the file as it appears in the commit.

Again, to go back to point #1, there is no *merging* here.  To *merge* you need *three* versions of a file; this selects *one* version—the version stored in the commit you choose—and says *write that version of the file to the index and to my work-tree*.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason the documentation says that this argument is a *tree-ish*, rather than a *commit* or *commit-ish*, is that you can use anything that resolves to one of Git's internal *tree* objects.  A commit does that, so a commit works; and there's never<sup>3</sup> any reason to use anything other than a commit hash ID here.

<sup>2</sup>I'm not in that habit myself, but usually I'll notice in a case in which omitting the `--` would cause a problem.  It would still be good for me to have it as a habit, in case I don't notice!

<sup>3</sup>Insert Gilbert & Sullivan routine here.

<sup>4</sup>The *index*, which Git also calls the *staging area*, is where you build your *next* commit.<sup>5</sup>  Your *work-tree* is where you can see and work with your files.  The files stored inside commits are kept in a special, read-only, Git-only, frozen-for-all-time format.  That makes them great for archival—which is a huge part of what a version control system is *about*, after all—but utterly useless for getting any actual *work* done.  Hence the *work-tree* or *working-tree*, which is where you have useful versions of files, as extracted from commits.

<sup>5</sup>This is a simplified picture: the index has several additional roles, especially during merging.  If you just think of it as holding a copy of every file from the *current* commit, perhaps updated so that the *next* commit will be different, you're usually close enough.  When you run `git commit`, Git does not use what's in your *work-tree*, but rather what's in the *index*.  This is why you must keep re-doing `git add` operations: `git add` means *copy the work-tree file back into the index, so that the new version is staged*, instead of having the old version staged.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and thoughtful answer. I'm not at work right now, so I can't experiment with my local repo, but I expect that I'll be able to get things sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If deleting the file and then doing the checkout restored the version from the previous `master` commit, then your local `master` hasn't been updated with the change.  So most likely either (a) your colleague hadn't pushed his changes, or (b) you hadn't pulled them into your local master.

You won't have any visibility to the change at all until it has both been pushed by your colleague, and fetched into your local repo.  Merely fetching it to your local repo doesn't update `master`, though, so if you don't want to `pull` into `master` (or `merge` into `master` after the `fetch`), you'd have to do something like

```
git checkout origin/master foo
```

(which does still depend on the change having been pushed and then fetched).

Whether you use `master` or `origin/master`, as noted in torek's post, it's better to add a `--` before the path, as in

```
git checkout master -- foo
```

as the added `--` resolves potential ambiguities about what some arguments mean.

If you're never going to locally modify the affected file, then that may be enough to do what you intend.  (Though, you are correct that it's not a good idea.)

If you have made any local change, or for any other convoluted reason your version has changed in ways that the `origin/master` version wouldn't reflect, this procedure will revert those changes.

To make sure credit is clearly given, all of this is covered in torek's answer, which goes into more detail.  I recommend reading and understanding it.  I rally only wrote this answer because based on the behavior you described, I believe this brings the immediate issues more front-and-center so perhaps you can more clearly see what's gone wrong.

Which is to say: just because I describe the behavior of this procedure, does not mean I endorse it.  There is NO right way to do the wrong thing.

Comment: I'm quite sure that master has new changes; I've got a separate local repo that has master checked out, so I can use regular diff to check. Your notion of using origin/master looks promising, though.

Comment: @user888379 - The point you might be missing, based on what you said there, is that the concept of "master [having] new changes" is a repo-specific concept.  Checking out `master` on another repo will not tell you whether a change is included in the current repo's `master` branch.  Your local picture of `origin/master` updates when you fetch , and your local `master` updates when you pull or merge, and those are all repo-specific operations

Comment: Thanks - I do get that. It really was a case where I intended to overwrite local branch contents with origin/master contents; I wasn't doing any work on those files on my branch, but I did need them to be available for building.

Answer (score 0):

Your described symptoms seem inconsistent to me, I'm going to answer as if you wanted to apply subsequent changes to the `master` copy of `foo` to your copy in "B".

The easy way is to directly ask git to apply the changes since the last time you looked at it, with `git apply`.  You do need to remember when was that last time you looked, that's up to you, you could add a comment in your copy of `foo` or keep it in a separate list, whatever.  I'm going to assume you've got a `last master merge from:  4a0ff3a2d9c42313a9b3b1bb59ba64334650fa74` line in your `foo` file, then the smoketest version of your update is

```
base=`awk '/last master merge from:/ {print $NF}' foo`
git diff $base master -- foo | git apply -3 
sed -si "1,/last master merge:/s/$base/`git rev-parse master`/" foo
```

you just need to remember to resolve any conflicts (changes you've made that overlap or abut changes since then on master).